# How to align image-text divs with flexbox?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, responsive

[image]

I was able to make it until the second row of the grid, but I'm perplexed about how to setup the divs with flexbox so that it looks like the image in mobile view. Should I put those 3 small divs in a bigger div? Or will a grid in grid will work best here? Also those 3 divs should be individual flexboxes to display like the image in mobile view, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Everything in the green box has to be flex.

Answer (score -1):

you can place the bottom 3 divs within a container div and set that to `flex`.  Then use a media query to control your responsive view and set that to `flex-direction: column` so the divs are stacked.

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="one">
  </div>

  <div class="two">
  </div>

  <div class="three">
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
}

// then at mobile width or whatever width you want, set the flex-direction to `column` so the divs are stacked and set the div widths to 100%;
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .one, .two, .three {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not the only issue. The image and the texts inside the small divs also have to be rearranged as in the picture.